# How can I register all the roles after the sentence I specified in discord.js to mongo (in the form of tags and ids)

Tags: discord.js

I'm doing a command in discord.js. I was able to register to mongo with only role tagging like .setup man role1 role2 role3. How can I do this with both id and tag? (I want it to save all roles after typing man
example

`if (message.mentions.roles.size >= 1) { select = message.mentions.roles.map(r => r.id); }else { if (!select) return select = args.splice(0, 1).map(id => message.guild.roles.cache.get(id)).filter(r => r != undefined); } }`
it only does if i tag the role

Answer (score 0):

In Discord, even if you tag the text is <@&role_id> will be like this. So you can basically make it with string methods.

```js
let args = message.content.split(" ").slice(1);
        args = args.filter(e => e)
        let data = {}
        let i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
            let roleStr = args[i]
            if(roleStr.startsWith("<@&")){
                let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleStr.slice(3, -1));
                data[i] = {tag: role.name, id: role.id}
            } else {
                    let role = message.guild.roles.cache.get(roleStr) || undefined;
                    if(role == undefined) return;
                    data[i] = {tag: role.name, id: role.id}
            }
        }
```

After this the data object will look like this;
[image]

The command template doesn't matter you tagged or wrote id, even if you write wrong it'll be okay dw;

[image]

Comment: I think, i misunderstood your question but anyway, this answer is contains your question too.